# Images move to next line on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

### Expected behavior

Images should scale down/up and stay in the same line

### Actual behavior

I created a row of images which should scale down on smaller devices, but they instead break into a new line.

---

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

### Code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- src omitted -->

<div style="margin:auto; display:table;">
  <img class="img-fluid" />  
  <img class="img-fluid" />  
  <img class="img-fluid" />
  <img class="img-fluid" />
  <img class="img-fluid" />
  <img class="img-fluid" /> 
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: scale down/up and stay in the same line? what exactly you want

Comment: The images should scale down on a smaller device and there shouldn't be a line break. All Images should stay in the same line.

Comment: This is not a good way to do things, rather than making things proportionally scale down you could consider stacking images or omitting some depending on the device.

Comment: Bootstrap is generally designed to make everything responsive and give a better experience to the user on all platforms. 

The framework is designed to give breakpoints to where it will flow down the page instead of across. What you are looking to do will squish the images down and make them difficult to see. 

If you are really set on them remaining on the same line, why not just combine them into one really long image on photoshop or similar program.

Comment: @JGallardo If that isn't a good way I will try to stack the images. Should I use the row and col class to achieve this?

Comment: @MooN_Tiga in making a decision i would factor things like how many images you will have maximum, the size of the images, and your targeted devices. do you have any mockups or sketches of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @MooN_Tiga give me a couple of days and I will prepare a blog post about this topic. Just to give you a few examples and things to consider. Will respond with a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox and keep the default `nowrap`

```css
.img-fluid {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1065">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1063">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1062">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1063">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1062">
</div>
```

And to scale on both direction you can add another container for the images:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069"></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1065"></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1063"></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1062"></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1063"></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1062"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had been using container-fluid, row, and col from bootstrap. This works so much better.

Comment: This answers the question but is a really bad way to do things as the image becomes distorted. also, if the image is in landscape size, it will even further get worsened in the presentation.

Comment: @JGallardo well, we are not here to judge the desicion made by others :) .. it's up to the OP to decide if it's *bad* or not depending on his use case as we have no idea about his situation. We simply try to give solution to problems

Comment: @TemaniAfif, i was just leaving the comment for anyone else who might stumble on this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `row` and `col` class from `bootstrap4` to achieve that.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81140/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also style them using `flexbox`.

[image]

**Note:** Make sure you use `align-items: flex-start;` or `align-items: center;` on the parent element, as `align-items: stretch;` is the **default** hence images will look horrible, like the accepted answer.

#### Updates:

The writer of the accepted answer said there is no difference when setting `align-items: flex-start;`. Here is the proof to show there is indeed: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81196/

[image]

The images without setting the `align-items` will default to `stretch` and they're stretched so much that I couldn't even capture them in the screenshot.

But yea the `stretch` effect might be what OP wants hence that's accepted answer.

Comment: you may notice that the class `image-list` is never used in your code, so the note you added is not relevant

Comment: and the note is still irrelevant, remove the align-items and see that it will behave the same ;) the stretch is ok in your case

Comment: You may also notice that boostrap is using flexbox so your second code is a simple duplicate of the first but using your style .. the only difference is the padding between col added by Boostrap and that you can remove using `p-0`

Comment: Maybe I was not clear on my statement. If the image is directly the flexbox child, you need to change `align-items` to either `flex-start` or whatever, unless you want it to be stretched out. Run the first code snippet off the accepted answer. You don't need that if you're wrapping the image with other element (doesn't have to be a div), which is better IMO because then `img-fluid` can take up 100% width of that image wrapper.

Comment: I have written the accepted answer ;) adding flex-start will not change the way the image are stretched (you can test it) and that *horrible* look was intended in case the OP need only a one side scale

Comment: adding `flex-start` is necessary if the images are the direct flexbox children, again, like the first code snippet of the accepted answer, just in case the OP would like to keep the image ratio LOL. You of course don't need that if the direct flexbox children are not the images, like the second code snippet of the accepted answer, which is added later on. I put down the note because I wanted to bring it up that `align-items: stretch;` is the default behavior.

Comment: try to add it to the first snippet code and see that it won't do nothing ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81178/. Take a look at the difference if you scale down the result window to like 120px. Setting the `align-items: flex-start;` will keep the images ratios. You have to resize the result window to that small in order to see the difference because your images are relatively small, 200px by 200px, where my test images are 4193px by 2785px.

Comment: there is exactly no difference between both ;) you can resize like you want and then scroll you will see no difference.

Comment: I wish I can post screenshot on comments, but whatever. I am not wasting time to argue over that.

Comment: you also forget to add `min-width:0;` to the image and still no difference ... the flex-start will change nothing simply because the image are defining the height